# Appending vectors. Result won't print

Tags: c++, vector, append

I'm trying to enter integers for a and b and then print those integers put together. For example, entering 1 2 3 4 for a and 4 3 2 1 for b would yield: 1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1. I don't understand why my program isn't printing this. Whenever I enter -1, nothing happens. Am I doing the process wrong while the program is running? Help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> append(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)

{
    int n = a.size();
    int m = b.size();

    vector<int> c(n + m);

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        c[i] = a[i];

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        c[n + i] = b[i];

    return c;

}
main()
{
    vector<int>a, b, c;
    int temp;

    cin >> temp;
    while (temp != -1) {
        a.push_back(temp);
        cin >> temp;
}

    cin >> temp;
    while (!cin.eof()) {
        b.push_back(temp);
        cin >> temp;
}

    c = append(a, b);
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
        cout << c[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: The second while loop in argument reading seems wrong.

Comment: What I'm doing is typing any integer, such as "23432" and hitting enter. Then typing another integer, such as "64364" and hitting enter. Then I enter -1. I thought this would print out "2343264364." It just prints a blank.

Comment: Your append function works, despite unnecessarily copying the input vectors. You should narrow the problem down and remove irrelevant code. If you have problems with code that is doing many different things, split it into single-responsibility parts and test each one of them in turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two loops, one to input the vector `a` and another to input `b`.
Hitting -1 once would terminate only the first loop. The second one is terminated by an `eof` which you still haven't entered. So either enter an `eof` (specific to your system) or have the second loop terminate at -1 (in which case you'll need to enter -1 once more).

Answer (score 0):

You say

> Whenever I enter -1, nothing happens.

That's because you reach the second `cin >> temp` statement at that time (just before `while.eof()` loop). That's when you start inputting values for `b` vector. You end that loop by entering EOF character in the stream (CTRL+Z on windows, CTRL+D on linux).